# python argparse: prefix or smart matching on sub parsers

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

Is it possible to add subparsers in python's (2.7) `argparse` that do not require an exact match when specifying which sub-command to execute?  Does anyone know how to do this?  It already does prefix matching on long options, e.g. `--my-long-option` can be specified as `--my-l` as long as it's a unique prefix among all of the other options.

For example, I want to have a command like

`foo apple
foo banana 
foo carrot`

Where I can just specify `foo ap` to use the `foo apple` subparser.

If I add these subparsers using the documented scheme, this does not work, i.e.

```
sub = parser.add_subparsers(help='commands')
apple = sub.add_parser( 'apple', ... )
banana = sub.add_parser( 'banana', ... )
carrot = sub.add_parser( 'carrot', ... )
```

This requires the full sub-command name to be specified.

Comment: It is possible to nest subparsers.  You could have a `foo` subparser, that in tern has `apple, banana, and carrot` subparsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note long options work with abbreviations.  In recent versions you can turn that off with `allow_abbrev=False` parameter.

Subparser names are handled with a different mechanism.  To the main parser, `add_subparsers(...)` creates a positional Action, with a `choices` parameter.

Your subparsers command is roughly equivalent to:

```
sp = parser.add_argument(dest='cmd', choices={'apple','banana', 'carrot'}, action=argparse._SubParsersAction, nargs='+...')
```

It's that `action` subclass that produces the unique subparser behavior.

As with regular `choices`, the test is

```
astring in choices
```

requiring an exact match, without any special abbreviations handing.

The 'aliases' parameter in `add_parser` can be used to approximate abbreviations.  From the documentation:

> Furthermore, add_parser supports an additional aliases argument, which allows multiple strings to refer to the same subparser. This example, like svn, aliases co as a shorthand for checkout:

A patch to allow abbreviations was proposed sometime ago.  It was committed last year, but then retracted because it had some bugs.

http://bugs.python.org/issue12713

> I [hpaulj] recommend closing this issue, and depend on aliases for subparsers abbreviations.  The interaction with 'choices' is just too complicated to handle as proposed here.

Comment: This works for python 3.2+, but unfortunately not for 2.7.5.  Based on the explanation and code walkthrough given in the answer, there's no way to do this in 2.7.5.

Comment: Looks like `aliases` was introduced in 2010, via http://bugs.python.org/issue9234, at a time when patching 2.7 and 3+ was not well coordinated.  The current system tries to apply a patch to both versions if possible.  I suspect the current 3.+ `add_parser` method could be monkey patched into a 2.7 file (or maybe the whole `_SubParsersAction` subclass.  I don't think the change uses any special 3.5 features.